# Check data from SQLite meets constraints like "number in range x-y"

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, constraints

I am writing a Python script that uses data of dubious quality. The data is being stored in an **SQLite database**.

I would like a compact way to specify constraints on the data. The constraints are of two types:

1. Data errors - an error message will be issued.

   - "Column A must be an integer in the range 0-10"
   - "Column B must be a non-blank string", and so forth.
2. Data quality warnings - "*are you sure this is right*?" A warning message will be issued. The constraints would be things like

   - "warn if Column C has a default value of 0" - are you sure the typist didn't miss an entry?
   - "warn if the number in Column D is unusually large (> 1000)".

Ideally, I would *like* to express my constraints in a human-readable format like:

```
'kV' MUST BE float IN RANGE 0-10
'Rating' SHOULD NOT BE DEFAULT 1.0
'Description' SHOULD NOT BE DEFAULT ""
```

... but I'll take any improvement on my current approach (below). I would be happy to accept a solution that involves enforcing the constraints in either Python or a SQLite schema.

Here's what I'm using at the moment:

```
 def is_number_in_range(number, expected_type, lower, upper):
    if type(number) != expected_type:
        return "not an %s" % expected_type
    elif ((number < lower) or (number > upper)):
        return "%s out of range [%i-%i]." % (expected_type, upper, lower)
    else:
        return "OK"

def not_default (value, expected_type, default_value):
    if type(value) != expected_type:
        return "not an %s" % expected_type
    elif value == default_value:
        return "default value of %s - make sure this is what you want." % default_value
    else:
        return "OK"

def Check_Cable_Lib(db_conn):
    res = db_conn.execute("SELECT * FROM Lib_Cable LIMIT 1")

    constraints = (
        ('kV', lambda x: is_number_in_range(x, float, 0, 1000) ),
        ('kA1', lambda x: is_number_in_range (x, float, 0, 10) ),
        ('kA1', lambda x: not_default(x, float, 1.0))
    )

    for cable_type in res:
        for constraint in constraints:
            constraint_variable = constraint[0]
            constraint_data = cable_type[constraint_variable]
            constraint_function = constraint[1]

            validation_message = constraint_function(constraint_data)
            print ("%(constraint_variable)s = %(constraint_data)s : %(validation_message)s" % locals())

stage1_db_path = "stage1.sqlite3";
db_conn = sqlite3.connect(stage1_db_path)
db_conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
Check_Cable_Lib(db_conn)
```

Example output:

```
kV = 11.0 : OK
kA1 = 1.0 : OK
kA1 = 1.0 : default value of 1.0 - make sure this is what you want.
```

**EDIT:** I'm aware it's impolite to explicitly check types in Python. However for the sake of the code that uses the data, I need to check that SQLite hasn't stored unexpected things in the columns ("hello world" in an INT column, etc.) Remember the data is of dubious quality and SQLite will happily put any type of data in any column. Catching these types of data entry errors is one of the objectives of this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining @onedaywhen's idea to use SQL to check the constraints, and @ABS's idea to define the constraints in a more readable way, here's what I've come up with.

Wrapping it up in a class probably isn't particularly useful (as used in the example it's a glorified wrapper around the `check()` function), but it means I can bake some slightly nicer output formatting into it later.

```
class Constraint:
    def __init__(self, table, column, constraint, error_or_warning):
        """
        examples:
            Constraint('Lib_Cable','kV', '> 0', 'error')
            Constraint('Lib_Cable','Insulation', '!= 0', 'warning')

        """
        self.table, self.column, self.constraint, self.error_or_warning = \
        table, column, constraint, error_or_warning

    def check (self, db_conn):
        c = db_conn.cursor()
        c.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

        query = "SELECT * FROM %(table)s WHERE NOT (%(column)s %(constraint)s)" % \
                {'table'      : self.table,
                 'column'     : self.column,
                 'constraint' : self.constraint }
        # [FIXME] start a transaction here - guard against novice SQL injections?
        res = c.execute(query)

        for row in res:
            print ( "%(error_or_warning)s: Row with key %(key)s in table %(table)s violates constraint %(column)s %(constraint)s)." % \
                {'key'        : row['KeyName'],
                 'table'      : self.table,
                 'column'     : self.column,
                 'constraint' : self.constraint,
                 'error_or_warning' : self.error_or_warning} )

        # [FIXME] discard transaction

Constraint_1 = Constraint('Lib_Cable', 'Insulation', '!= 0', 'error')        
Constraint_1.check(db_conn)
```

Answer (score 3):

The following article may be of interest:

[Verbalizing Business Rules by Terry Halpin](http://www.orm.net/pdf/VBR16.pdf)

> Alethic rules impose necessities, which cannot, even in principle, be
>   violated by the business, typically because of some physical or
>   logical law. For example: each employee was born on at most one date;
>   no product is a component of itself. Deontic rules impose obligations,
>   which may be violated, ven though they ought not. For example: it is
>   obligatory that each employee is married to at most one person; no
>   smoking is permitted in any office.

From a SQL point of view, look to write a query to return data that would violate the rule e.g.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM T 
 WHERE Column_A < 0
```

Then test that each rule is the empty set. Look to make them granular e.g. having separate tests for `Column_A < 0` and `Column_A > 10` respectively.

Comment: Good idea - offload the heavy lifting to SQL. As a bonus the error reporting is much easier for the end user to interpret - the output of `SELECT id FROM Column_A WHERE [constraint]` is pretty much all they need to go back and fix the problems in the original data.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use a slightly more complex implementation, you could use a dictionary of dictionaries:

A specification could be:

```
{
'kv':{'type':'float','range':(0,10)},
'Rating':{'not':1.0}
}
```

Comment: Not bad; about as human readable as you're going to get without actually writing a (simple) parser.

Comment: Ended up using a CSV file with columns for "table", "column", "constraint", "severity" and "explanation". Human editable in the sense my target audience (engineers) can open it in Excel.